# Change a multiple value field to use divs instead of a table in node/add?

Tags: 7, entities

I have the # of values set to 10, which I want to put in 2 columns of 5 each, but I don't know how to change the table structure to accomplish this, or perhaps preferably, just change it to use divs so I do it with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`theme_field_multiple_value_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.form.inc/function/theme_field_multiple_value_form/7), e.g.

```
function MYTHEME_field_multiple_value_form($vars) {
  // Copy code from theme_field_multiple_value_form() and change as appropriate
}
```

It's not a short function, and you'll probably be reproducing a bunch of code, but it uses `theme_table()` directly so it can't be solved with a preprocess function.